# How to fit VAR after differencing (Error:NA in y)?

Tags: time-series, missing-data, vector-autoregression, error-message, differencing

I want to run VAR model by using `vars::VAR`. Since my X1 was not stationary, I differenced it by `diff(data$X1)`, then got a data frame like the below picture. However, I got an error: `Error in VAR(train, ic = AIC) : NAs in y.`

*Should I remove the whole row1?* I'm not quite sure, since this may cause loss of information.
Or, *are there are other ways to deal with this error?*

I did not find much discussion about how to deal with data after making a non-stationary data to stationary data by differencing, hope can get some insight.

```
 data=data.frame(X1=c(NA,runif(10,0,1)),X2=runif(11,0,1),Y=runif(11,0,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to remove the whole first row. If your sample is not very small, you should be just fine. You could also see how much of a difference removing the first row makes by inserting some plausible values instead of the NA and inspecting by how much your parameter estimates change in each case.

Techniques that do not remove the first row are much more involved; e.g. you could use a Kalman filter or the EM algorithm for both estimating the model's parameters and filling in the missing values (here just one). But if you sample is not very small, this option is not likely to be worth the effort.

Comment: Oh, so basically it's same method as handling ordinary missing value? I worried that it'll break the stationarity so did not realized about this.

Comment: @S.F.Yeh, yes, it can be considered a missing value.